# Automatically detecting an existing white border around a batch of inages

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, script, actionscript

Looking for a way to detect an existing white border around a batch of images before/while executing an action to remove the border and upscale to original size.

Happy for the detection of border and sorting to occur separately to running a batch script to remove the border/upscale.

Additional info: I have a set of 10,000+ images, some of which have a thick white border around them that needs to be removed. Automation is the key here.

Comment: What have you tried? where is that failing?

Comment: I’m asking for suggestions to detect a white border in photos automatically because I’m out of ideas.

Comment: What ideas have you tried before you ran out? Are all the "borders" the same width? This question reads as if you are asking someone to *write* a script/action for you. We aren't a scripting service. If you share what you've tried, there may be some suggestions to make those efforts work for you.

Comment: Perhaps select by colour range, invert, and crop?  As for scaling up, if you know how thick the border was in every photo you could work out the percentage and scale the image by percentage. If that works, you could save it as an action, and apply the action using file > automate > batch.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer, because success may depend on the photos, for example if there are white/blown out areas around the edge, select by colour range may not work well when trying to find the borders.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Billy. The difficulty is in detecting the images with a 100px border first, before processing a crop action. Some images have content right to the edge, the ones I'm targeting specifically have a 100px white border around it on all sides.